# How to remotely execute a command via a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

So basically, all I want to do is execute an "sc" command on 100 servers whose names are mentioned in a text file "server.txt". I tried the following and it doesnt work as it returns empty notepad file.

```
for /f %%a in (servers.txt) do sc \\server_name query | find "SERVICE_NAME">>servicecontroller.txt
```

I tried the above command locally and it worked just fine. I know the issue is in the "\server_name". Not sure what about it is wrong. Do i need to use the hidden shares?
Like this maybe?

```
\\server_name\c$ /user:domain\username password
```

Or like this?

```
 \\server_name\c$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've hardcoded `\\server_name` there rather than `%%a`, then that's your problem.  Try this instead:

```
for /f %%a in (servers.txt) do sc \\%a query | find "SERVICE_NAME">>servicescontroller.txt
```

EDIT :
The following line helps in getting admin access consistently on all the servers. This is the line I(OP) was looking for.

```
net use \\servername\ipc$ /u:domain\user password
```

Comment: I did do the "%%a" thing. Did not hard code it. The problem is I'm having a permissions issue thats why I am not sure if I should use domain mode with user & pass.

Comment: I'll +1 u anyway... since you are on the right track at least.

Comment: Ah, I see.  sc does assume you have admin access to those remote machines as your currently logged in account.  If you're trying to use different credentials, then I'd use: net use \\servername\ipc$ /u:domain\user password  

Insert standard caveats about having passwords in plaintext.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. I'll try that later tonight. Will let you know if that was the issue.

Comment: So yea that little trick fixed it. Using the domain user and pass. wmz's solution also works after I input domain user and pass and run wmic in 2 different batches though-1 for 2003 and 1 for 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute commands on remote machines in a network using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). I use it to execute batch files and pass parameters to them, as well as checking for running services. There's even a special syntax to execute on a number of computers listed in a text file.

Alternatively, if powershell is an option, you may consider using [powershell remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, I wud prefer only a batch solution without having to install PSexec

Answer (score 1):

As alternative way, you could use wmic for that:

Execute against many machines at once and save list as nicely formatted html table (among other formats):

```
wmic /node:@servers.txt /output:services.html service get caption /format:htable
```

Of course you may query many more attributes besides names/captions.

Comment: I have already tried that. The limitation is what u stated. I cannot "just" get the service names.

Comment: @Gutsygibbon If it does not fit your needs, so be it. You're code master :) but I'm not sure what you mean. You can get text file with just service name per line (using `get name`) if you omit `/format`. Does include 'name' as fist line, but you can easily get rid of that.

Comment: Hmm,I didn't mention the issue at all in my last post. The problem is we have 2 different kinds of servers(2003 and 2008). Since both have different versions of Windows Installer and SNMP, WMIC is different in both. And, even with WMIC I still have authentication issues on some remote servers(I feel its an issue with our LDAP server). I wanted a way in which specific credentials can be specified to access the servers and then run sc or wmic. The issue bottles down to that credential thing again. Sorry, saying "I cannot "just" get the service names." didn't justify anything haha.