# Openfiles query to see open files

Tags: powershell, command-line, vbscript, command-prompt, dsquery

How can I call the Openfiles.exe (which is on the server 2008 file server) remotely from a computer to see which files are open by the users? I also need to have it login as the domain admin user in the parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remotely execute a command via a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430049/how-to-remotely-execute-a-command-via-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openfiles can do a server direct. You don't have to run it remotely.

From Help `openfiles /query /?`

```
OPENFILES /Query /S system /U username /P password /NH
```

Comment: Yes but I need to run it from the user's workstation not the server.

Comment: User needs to see who has the file open on the file-server on occasional basis.

Comment: Why can't they run their own copy? They have a copy too. But they can run any copy they want from any server. `\\server\share\windows\openfiles.exe`

Comment: So a user from a workstation (windows 7) can run this command from the command prompt which would trigger the file server and would show how has what file open on the shared drives?

Comment: They will see what they have permission to see what they are allowed to. But they can specify a different username/password if they wish. `openfiles /s servername`.

Comment: What would be the correct synatx to specify a username and password?

Comment: It's in my answer. The general form is `username@domain` or `domain\username`.

Comment: Thank you I got it. Is there anyway I can specif in the command line to only show open files in a particular folder?

Comment: Use a filter `openfiles /query | findstr /i /c:"some part of a folder name"`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work: c:\Windows\System32>openfiles.exe /query | findstr /i /E:"/FolderName/FolderNAme2" /S ServerIP /
U ServerName\administrator /P Passwprd /FO csv /v >C:\test\test.csv

Comment: `openfiles.exe /query /S Serenity /U "Serenity\David Candy"
/p "Pass" /FO csv /v | findstr /i /C:"Documents" > C:\test\test.csv`

Comment: Note `/c:"documents"` c: is NOT a drive letter. Don't change it. Type `findstr /?`

Comment: @trigger - is there a way to get a list of the files for all users *but* the admin user, so I could close the open files? let's say I want to exclude 'devadmin' user from the list - but want to find and close all other files...

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it in PowerShell and to allow for searching would be with this small function.

```
function Get-OpenFiles {
    cls
    openfiles /query /s $args[0] /fo csv /V | Out-File -Force C:\temp\openfiles.csv
    $search = $args[1]
    Import-CSV C:\temp\openfiles.csv | Select "Accessed By", "Open Mode", "Open File (Path\executable)" | Where-Object {$_."Open File (Path\executable)" -match $search} | format-table -auto
    Remove-Item C:\temp\openfiles.csv
}
```

It allows you to call `Get-OpenFiles Server Filename` and it will show you the results. The caveat is that you have a folder called C:\temp.

So if I do `Get-OpenFiles TestServer Hardware` I get the below.

```
Accessed By Open Mode    Open File (Path\executable)
----------- ---------    ---------------------------
NFDJWILL    Read         N:\Network Services\Documentation\Hardware.xlsx
NFDJWILL    Write + Read N:\Network Services\Documentation\Hardware.xlsx
NFDJWILL    Read         N:\Network Services\Documentation\Hardware.xlsx
```

Comment: Note: You can do this without using a temp file by piping your openfiles command into ConvertFrom-CSV then piping into Select like so: openfiles /query /s blah /fo csv /V | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select "Open Mode"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without creating temporary files.

```
function Get-OpenFile
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    $openfiles = openfiles.exe /query /s $computerName /fo csv /V

    $openfiles | ForEach-Object {

        $line = $_

        if ($line -match '","')
        {
            $line
        }

    } | ConvertFrom-Csv
}

Get-OpenFile -ComputerName server1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this with the PowerShell command Get-SmbOpenFile.

Answer (score 0):

how to run application remotely by using Power Shell
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx

your PS or BAT script will be:

```
openfiles.exe > c:\temp\openfiles.txt
```

of course better use different output folder and file name.

Alternative way:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx -- PsExec -- *PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software.*

Comment: but where would I specify the remote server name on this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a remote delegated powershell session for this.

[Use Delegated Administration and Proxy Functions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/03/use-delegated-administration-and-proxy-functions.aspx)

You can delegate the admin credentials in RunAs setting of the session configuration, and constrain the session to only being able to run the openfiles.exe.  Then you can assign permission to use to session to selected groups or users. This enables you to let people run cmdlets or programs that require domain admin authority, without giving them the domain admin credentials.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a CSV file and have to remove it later, or be concerned about its' size.

```
openfiles /s MyFileSrv /query /fo CSV /v /u admin1 /p myPass | convertfrom-csv  |?{$_.'Open File (Path\executable)' -match "MyFolder"} |select 'Accessed By', 'Open Mode', 'Open File (Path\executable) 

Accessed By Open Mode    Open File (Path\executable)
----------- ---------    ---------------------------
robinsonl   Write + Read D:\Dept\MyFolder
smithd      Read         D:\Dept\MyFolder\info
```

If you're using powershell 1.0 then add |select -skip 8| before the convertfrom-csv portion.